# Ubuntu 22.04 docker in docker cgroups

Tags: systemd

I'm running a TeamCity agent on Ubuntu 22.04 as a docker container and then running a docker container within that. I have successfully done this on Ubuntu 20.04, but I'm hitting a cgroups systemd issue on 22.04 and can not fathom a way around it.

"docker: Error response from daemon: cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown."
From various sources, I've added  --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd to /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service ExecStart command and this has made no difference.

Command:

- docker run --rm --privileged --user %env.UID% container-name
- docker run --rm --privileged container-name
- docker run --rm --user %env.UID% container-name

Any suggestions?
Thanks